# Check for instance of Python multiprocessing.Connection?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, typechecking, python-multiprocessing

`Connection` objects are created when opening a `multiprocessing.Pipe`. However, it's not clear how to check whether an object is an instance of a `Connection`.

In Python3 (3.4, 3.3, !3.2), to detect an instance of `Connection` I can do:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Connection

if isinstance(f, Connection):
  print("f is a Connection to a Pipe")
```

`from multiprocessing.dummy.connection import Connection` also works on all Python3, but not Python2.

However, this results in an `ImportError` using Python2. How am I supposed to reliably check for a Connection object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are significant implementation differences between Python 2 and 3 w. r. t. multiprocessing Connection objects. In Python 2, you can import them via:

```
from _multiprocessing import Connection
```

In Python 2, the `Connection` class is implemented in a helper module `_multiprocessing`, written in C (source [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/2.7/Modules/_multiprocessing)). I think it is written in C for better accessibility of the Windows API and possibly for performance reasons. I assume that in case of Python 3 the special Windows API calls required for implementing named pipes have been externalized to the winapi module.

You can easily, depending on the Python version, either import Connection from `multiprocessing.connection` or from `_multiprocessing` so that your code runs on both, Python 2 and 3.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other things that your object might be are rather different from a Connection, you can do something like:

```
if hasattr(f, 'recv'):
     print("f can be received from")
```

This will be portable without having to import the private class in Python 2.