# Python check isinstance multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using python 2.7 multiprocessing on windows 7:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from Queue import Queue
from multiprocessing.managers import AutoProxy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    myqueue = manager.Queue()

    print myqueue
    print type(myqueue)
    print isinstance(myqueue, Queue)
    print isinstance(myqueue, AutoProxy)
```

Output:

```
<Queue.Queue instance at 0x0000000002956B08>
<class 'multiprocessing.managers.AutoProxy[Queue]'>
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/TryHere.py", line 12, in <module> print 
  isinstance(myqueue, AutoProxy) TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a 
  class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

My question is: I would like to check if a variable is an instance of a multiprocessing queue, how should i go about checking?

I have referred to:

[Check for instance of Python multiprocessing.Connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549738/check-for-instance-of-python-multiprocessing-connection)

[Accessing an attribute of a multiprocessing Proxy of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499548/accessing-an-attribute-of-a-multiprocessing-proxy-of-a-class)

but they dont seem to address my issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Question**: I would like to check if a variable is an instance of a multiprocessing queue, how should i go about checking?

It's a Proxy object, `multiprocessing.managers.BaseProxy` does match:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseProxy
print(isinstance(myqueue, BaseProxy))
>>>True
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.6, the equivalent would be

```
import multiprocessing
test_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
type(test_queue) == multiprocessing.queues.Queue:
>>> True
```

We can choose not to perform a type-check upon a newly created Queue object as proposed by @mikeye

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.10, we can use the Queue under the `queues` namespace, while still using `isinstance()`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
my_q = mp.Queue()
isinstance(my_q, mp.queues.Queue)
>>> True

import asyncio
isinstance(my_q, asyncio.Queue)
>>> False

import queue
isinstance(my_q, queue.Queue)
>>> False
```

I know this doesn't exactly cover the original question, but since the error is much the same as with only using `mp.Queue` instead of `mp.queues.Queue`, I thought I'd add this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
my_queue = mp.Queue()
print(type(my_queue) == type(mp.Queue()))
>>>True
```